# SQL Update - Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I would like to update multiple columns in a table based on values from a second table using a `Select` statement to obtain the values like this:

```
UPDATE tbl1 
SET (col1, col2, col3) = (SELECT colA, colB, colC 
                          FROM tbl2 
                          WHERE tbl2.id = 'someid') 
WHERE tbl1.id = 'differentid'
```

However, it doesn't seem as though it's possible to 'SET' more than one column name - are there alternatives rather than writing separate update statements for each column?

```
UPDATE tbl1 
SET col1 = (SELECT colA FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.id = 'someid') 
WHERE tbl1.id = 'differentid'

UPDATE tbl1 
SET col2 = (SELECT colB FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.id = 'someid') 
WHERE tbl1.id = 'differentid'

UPDATE tbl1 
SET col3 = (SELECT colC FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.id = 'someid') 
WHERE tbl1.id = 'differentid'
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
update tbl1
set col1 = a.col1, col2 = a.col2, col3 = a.col3
from tbl2 a
where tbl1.Id = 'someid'
and a.Id = 'differentid'
```

Answer (score 7):

This should work -

```
    Update Tbl1 
    SET 
    Col1 = B.ColA,
    Col2 = B.ColB,
    Col3 = B.ColC
    FROM
    Tbl2 B
    Where
    B.Id = 'Someid'
```

Comment: both tables do not share the same id, as seen in the question, so can I put a where clause for b.id = 'someid' and tbl1.id = 'differentid'