# Two or more results of one CASE statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Is it possible to `SELECT` value of two or more columns with one shot of `CASE` statement? I mean instead of:

```
select 
 ColumnA = case when CheckColumn='condition' then 'result1' end
,ColumnB = case when CheckColumn='condition' then 'result2' end
```

Something like:

```
select case when CheckColumn='condition' then ColumnA='result1', ColumnB='result2' end
```

**UPDATE**
Just the same as we can do with the UPDATE statement:

```
update CTE
set ColumnA='result1', ColumnB='result2'
where CheckColumn='condition'
```

Comment: All i can ask is why?

Comment: No it is not possible using `CASE` expression.

Comment: @Kaf for the clearance of code when the stress is on condition, not on the results.

Comment: @Fireblade For the performance. Doesn't it check the same condition many times? I looked for the logic of update of multiple columns with one condition in an UPDATE statement http://stackoverflow.com/a/15881737/1903793

Comment: Might be worth classifying this: in the text you say you want to do an `UPDATE` but your examples show `SELECT`. Could you change either the text or the examples to make the question consistent?

Comment: It is not possible to do this in a case statement. In your first code block you set the value of each column separately using a case statement which is of course correct. But in the second code block you put the case statement directly after the select statement, which is just not allowed. Just use the first option. Or you could go for a solution as posted below using CROSS APPLY or a CTE.

Comment: Do you have only one type of condition to execute update statement or multiple conditions & multiple updates ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with `CASE` expression. 
For every column you need new `CASE`

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, but you could use a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dd776382%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) as a work around to this, to store each value for columna and columnb against your check column:

```
SELECT  t.CheckColumn,
        v.ColumnA,
        v.ColumnB
FROM    dbo.YourTable AS t
        LEFT JOIN 
        (VALUES
            ('Condition1', 'Result1', 'Result2'),
            ('Condition2', 'Result3', 'Result4'),
            ('Condition3', 'Result5', 'Result6')
        ) AS v (CheckColumn, ColumnA, ColumnB)
            ON v.CheckColumn = t.CheckColumn;
```

If you have more complex conditions, then you can still apply this logic, but just use a pseudo-result for the join:

```
SELECT  t.CheckColumn,
        v.ColumnA,
        v.ColumnB
FROM    dbo.YourTable AS t
        LEFT JOIN 
        (VALUES
            (1, 'Result1', 'Result2'),
            (2, 'Result3', 'Result4'),
            (3, 'Result5', 'Result6')
        ) AS v (ConditionID, ColumnA, ColumnB)
            ON v.ConditionID = CASE WHEN <some long expression> THEN 1
                                    WHEN <some other long expression> THEN 2
                                    ELSE 3
                                END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent `select` to the `update` is:

```
select 'result1', 'result2'
. . .
where CheckColumn = 'condition';
```

Your `select` is different because it produces `NULL` values.  There is an arcane way you can essentially do this with `outer apply`:

```
select t2.*
from . . . outer apply
     (select t.*
      from (select 'result1' as col1, 'result2' as col2) t
      where CheckColumn = 'condition'
     ) t2;
```

This will return `NULL` values when there is no match.  And, you can have as many columns as you would like.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you want to update multiple columns if certain condition is true.

For such situation you have to use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) statements.

Example of using MERGE is as given on [msdn here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

**Code example:**

```
-- MERGE statement for update.
USE [Database Name];
GO
MERGE Inventory ity
USING Order ord
ON ity.ProductID = ord.ProductID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET ity.Quantity = ity.Quantity - ord.Quantity;
```

More MERGE statement example [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-merge-statement-in-sql-server-2008/).

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this maybe with a CTE or a CROSS APPLY, somehting like

```
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(inx INT, val1 VARCHAR(10),val2 VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO @tbl2 VALUES(1,'value1a','value1b'),(2,'value2a','value2b'),(3,'value2a','value2b');

UPDATE yourTable SET col1=subTable.val1,col2=subTable.val2
FROM yourTable
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT val1,val2
    FROM @tbl2
    WHERE inx=1 --YourCondition
) AS subTable
```